# How to send HTML email with multiple Images

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

i want to send html mail with multiple images. i am using webbrowsercontrol to embedded multiple images but when i send mail HTML email along with Image in HTML then  I receive only html mail without Image.!

Answer (score 5):

Try  with [**LinkedResource**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.linkedresource.aspx) Class to embed the image

```
using System.Net.Mail;

string messageHtml= @"<html><body> Your message text 
                  <img src=""cid:12345"" />
                  <img src=""cid:123456"" /></body></html>";
AlternateView view= AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(messageHtml, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

LinkedResource pic= new LinkedResource("pics.jpg", MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
pic.ContentId = "12345";

LinkedResource pic2= new LinkedResource("pic2.jpg", MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
pic2.ContentId = "123456";
view.LinkedResources.Add(pic);
view.LinkedResources.Add(pic2);

MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.AlternateViews.Add(view);

mail.send();
```

Comment: i want to add multiple images.

Comment: is this problem solved?? am also having same requirement. In my case images are going as attachments.

Comment: @KeerthiKumar, Yes I have implemented this in one of my project where we send the images as embedded resources instead of urls. The urls were blocked by client network, hence its the best approach to send them as attached images

Comment: @Murali  for me also its working nw. But am facing one more problem ie, am unable attach a background image for my mail. Here my mail contains div tag for this am trying to apply background image

Comment: @KeerthiKumar, For those better you can use inline css along with absolute url, where the image url is hosted. i.e `<div style='background:url('http://server/images/logo.jpeg')'>`